# Synchronization of tx and rx in sdr

Tags: python, gnuradio, software-defined-radio, synchronization

I am implementing a FMCW radar using bladerf sdr:
[image]

When reading the output from the vector sinks, the outputs are not synchronised.How should I synchronise them? is it possible to do so using gnuradio only or should I write some HDL code?

**EDIT**
rx signal:
[image]

tx signal:
[image]

The object distance is only few meters. The x scale is in seconds. That cant be the delay.

Comment: In what sense they are not synchronised? Is it possible to add some plots to your post showing this lack of synchronisation?

Comment: added several plots of tx and rx signals, you can see that the delay between them. that is the time scale from gnuradio.

Comment: The x scale is in seconds.